# How to add HTML to head tag in MediaWiki without using an extension?

Tags: php, html, mediawiki

I desire to add HTML to the head tag of all web pages of a MediaWiki (1.33) website I have.

I found no documentation (or no clear answers in QA sessions) about how to do this.

This brought me to try to add it via JavaScript this way:

```
var templateLiteral = [`
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-VALUE",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
    });
    </script>
`]

var head = document.querySelector("head");
head.innerHTML += templateLiteral;
```

This seems to work but is considered unconventional because as a general rule, search engine crawlers don't run scripts in `<script>` tag (Google seems to do run them, but Google is in a minority here).

I found no template PHP file for HTML and PHP, because MediaWiki doesn't have a template engine (such as Twig).

**How to add HTML to `head` tag in MediaWiki without using an extension?**
I have only one extension (ContactPage) and I humbly plan to stay this way...

Comment: I know you don't want an extension, but just in case you change your  mind: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HeadScript

Comment: You can dump the code that would normally live in an extension into LocalSettings.php (in this case something like `$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function (OutputPage $out ) { $out->addScript( '<script...' ); };`). Not that it has any advantage over using an actual extension, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to answer this but for people looking out for the same this could be achieved using LocalSettings.php, just include the following code:

```
// Define a function to append the HTML code to the <head> tag
function add_html_to_head(&$out, &$skin) {
    $out->addHeadItem('my_html_code', 'add_your_script_or_html_here');
}
// Register the function to the BeforePageDisplay hook
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'add_html_to_head';
```

The above code will directly add anything you would add in **add_your_script_or_html_here** to your MediaWiki's head tag.

Hope this would help : )